# LINQPad index out of range exception

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

When I run this code

```
var res = from name in Util.Cmd (@"dir")
          where name[0] == '1'
          select name;

res.Dump();
```

I get a directory listing, then an `IndexOutofBoundsException` when the `res.Dump()` line is evaluated. I was expecting to see a directory listing followed by another listing showing only the lines where the first character is a `1`.

However, if I run:

```
var res = from name in Util.Cmd (@"dir")
          where name.Length > 1 && name[0] == '1'
          select name;

res.Dump();
```

I get the expected behaviour (i.e. all lines greater than 1 in length and starting with `1`). No exception is thrown.

So my question is, why does the first code segment result in an exception?

Comment: One of your names is an empty string.

Comment: Oh God...how embarrassing. Of course you are correct. I'm going to bed now, it's clearly too late for my brain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where name[0] == '1'` clause isn't actually evaluated until you run the `Dump` command.  Before then it's just a delay executed query.  The problem is one of the values returned by `Util.Cmd` is the empty string and hence you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`